# Polynomials on finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

How can I calculate the greatest common divisor of two polynomials in a finite field?

I know it's through the Euclidean algorithm, but I don't know how to apply it to the finite fields case.

If I have $f(x)=x^4+3x^3+2x^2+4$ and $g(x)=x^2+3x+2$ in $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$

How I could get $\gcd(f(x), g(x))$.

I have done this (Euclidean algorithm), but it doesn't coincide with your results:

https://screenshotscdn.firefoxusercontent.com/images/7abcb560-ec5b-453a-b71d-8b794548b267.png

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just apply the Euclidean algorithm as usual. One only needs to take care not dividing by zero. Since $\mathbb{F}_5$ is a field, this is all.

Comment: Usual Euclidean. Start out with $$\gcd(f(x),g(x)=\gcd(f(x)-x^2g(x),g(x))=\gcd(4,x^2+3x+2).$$ Here you are done after a single step, because the remainder was a constant.

Comment: I have uploaded an image that shows what I have done, but I don't know what it is incorrect.

Comment: @mathandtic: It looks like what you did is correct: You get $4$ as a gcd. This is like getting $-1$ as a gcd for $-5$ and $3$ in $\Bbb Z$. (And actually, $4=-1$ in $\Bbb{F}_5$.) A gcd in a ring like this is only defined up to multiplication with a unit, so actually 1,2,3 and 4 are all gcd's of your two polynomials.

Comment: I don't know understand why $4 = -1 in F_5$  Because, 4 is in $F_5$

Comment: $4 \equiv -1$ mod $5$.

Answer (score 4):

The Euclidean algorithm works over any field $K$, also over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. Here we do not really need it, because
$$
g(x)=(x+1)(x+2).
$$
So all we need to test is, whether $x=-1$ or $x=-2$ is a root of $f(x)$.
This is not the case, over $\mathbb{F}_5$, hence
$$
\gcd(f,g)=1.
$$

Comment: Thanks. For all fields, I could try to find the roots of the polynomial. And if it doesn't coincide then is 1?

Comment: Yes, the possible gcd's only could be (up to a unit), $1$, $x+1$ or $x+2$, and "if doesn't coincide", then it is $1$.

Answer (score 3):

Just doing the division gives $f(x)=x^2g(x)+4$ and therefore any common divisor will be a factor of the remainder, $4$. That's essentially all Euclid's algorithm does, though it generally takes more steps than this.

Modulo $5$, we have that $4\equiv -1$ is a unit - the non-zero elements form a field. So the greatest common divisor is $1$. [Note that such divisors are only determined, in general, up to multiplication by a unit]

Comment: But, I get confused by performing the euclidean division into finite fields. Could you do step by step, please?

Comment: I have upload how I did.